# I can't add Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common to my ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

I am trying to add a reference to the above assembly but it does not appear in my ASP.NET MVC .NET 4 (Not client) applications Assembly list. Does anyone know how to reference this Assembly?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common` namespace resides in the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll` assembly.

> [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common Namespace (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.aspx)

Assuming the default installation folders you can find the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll` assembly in:

> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\XXXX\SDK\Assemblies`

Where `XXXX` represents the version of SQL Server you're running:

```
80  -> SQL Server 2005
90  -> SQL Server 2008
100 -> SQL Server 2008R2
```

If you're running SQL Server 32bit on x64 then instead of `c:\Program Files` use `c:\Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: "Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll" - I was looking forever for this guy! Thanks. Good job on the naming, MS.