# Execute sql script on SQL server using C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008r2-express

SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, .Net Framework 4.0, Visual Studio 2010

I'm trying to execute a SQL script from a command prompt application. I found a [sample](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/43e8bc3a-1132-453b-b950-09427e970f31)
code and trying to implement the same. But the following using statements are not recognized.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
```

Am I missing any assembly reference ?

Comment: your question seems to be related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879987/i-cant-add-microsoft-sqlserver-management-common-to-my-asp-net-mvc-application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely are, you need the assemblies that are included with the SDK that comes with SQL server. [Be sure you installed the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162189.aspx) when you installed SQL server.

(screenshot taken from a random google image search, the highlighted item is what you need)
[image]

By default they are located at a path similar to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies` The version number may be different for the version of SQL server you have installed.

Comment: Thanks for the info Scott. I had to add refernce to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Following c# code uses SMO(SQL Server Management Object) to read any
>   sql query from a .sql file and execute on SQL server.

```
 #region Using Directives

    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System;

    #endregion

    public sealed class DatabaseHandler
    {
        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the Database Connection String
        /// </summary>
        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbConnectionString"];
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads the script conent from .sql file and execute on SQl Server
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="scriptFilePath">.sql Script file path</param>
        /// <returns>Operation status <c>true: Success</c><c>false: Failed</c></returns>
        public bool ExecuteScript(string scriptFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                bool isCreated = false;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(scriptFilePath))
                {
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(scriptFilePath);

                    if (null != fileInfo)
                    {
                        //Holds the sql script as string
                        string scriptText = string.Empty;

                        using (StreamReader reader = fileInfo.OpenText())
                        {
                            if (null != reader)
                            {
                                scriptText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }

                        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                        {
                            Server sqlServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));

                            if (null != sqlServer && null != sqlServer.ConnectionContext)
                            {
                                sqlServer.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(scriptText);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                isCreated = true;
                return isCreated;
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find" + scriptFilePath);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that it's 2017, there is an easier way.

Add this NuGet package: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects