# C# Windows Application Deployment

Tags: c#, deployment

I developed a windows application using C# that has a database. The database is attached to my local SQL Server Management Studio. Now, I want to deploy my application (C# + database) so that it can be simply installed on other computers using an installer (setup file). I'm so new in this field. Please guide me that what steps I should follow to do this. Thank you.

Comment: First off, find a host for your SQL server database, unless you want to have the end-user host their own. When you have that, you'll need to find a way to expose your data to the client without actually exposing the credentials used to log in to your database, if you don't want to end up being abused. Web services or something similar (WCF) could be something you want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these,

1) First get some idea on how to create `MSI` within `Installer Class` [Read](http://devcity.net/PrintArticle.aspx?ArticleID=339)

2) Create a command prompt app which should have the logic to create a Database in local SQL server. [Check my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030331/execute-sql-script-on-sql-server-using-c-sharp/17324190#17324190)

3) Pack the command prompt exe with the MSI package.

4) Within the insatller class's `Install()` method write logic to execute the command prompt exe.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to consider before going for deployment.

1. Do you have a centralized application? Meaning do you want to host your database on server or you want to deploy on each users machine.If you want it to be centralized then how are you going to access the database. Does your current structure supports it? like are you using SOA to access db or anything else?
2. If you have decided that you want to deploy your database along with your application on your client machine then you will have to deploy your database along with your setup. You can read a tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16231/Deploy-your-Application-and-Database) on how to achieve this.