# How to create setup file of window form application in visual studio 2010 with mssql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I am using inbuilt visual studio database(mssql) for my app,  how can i marge this with setup?
I have tried many options and also tried setup factory to do this but not get success.
Please suggest if you have any idea.
Thanks.

Comment: easy way just put your SQL file where your setup folder generated

Comment: i used this but on a client computer a exception occurred can not find sql server and user instance not created.

Comment: because on client machine have not set of SQL which you are using on your machine check your path and scripts

Comment: how can i install sql on client machine by my application?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751927/how-to-add-my-sql-server-2008-r2-database-to-my-visual-studio-2010-setup-file) link.