# How can I take backup of mysql database

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

When I try to backup mysql database I am not getting `ExportToFile` instead its showing export in the line shown as comment statement. How could I achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
private void Backup()
{
   string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=;database=testdb;Allow Zero Datetime=true";
   string file = "D:\\sss.sql";

   MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring);
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
   MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd);

   cmd.Connection = conn;
   conn.Open();
   mb.Export(file);  //mb.ExportToFile//                   
   conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: How you tried ExportToFile? what it says when you do that `mb.ExportToFile(file)`?

Comment: have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030331/execute-sql-script-on-sql-server-using-c-sharp) thread ?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."the following error is thrown at line MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd);

Comment: Error 14 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBackup' does not contain a definition for 'exporttofile' and no extension method 'exporttofile' accepting a first argument of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBackup' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)