# Run a SQL script programmatically

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute an .SQL script file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c)

How would I programmatically run a SQL script that's in a file on the local disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer taken from here [How to execute an .SQL script file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c)

Put the command to execute the sql script into a batch file then run the below code

```
string batchFileName = @"c:\batosql.bat";
string sqlFileName = @"c:\MySqlScripts.sql";
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = batchFileName;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = sqlFileName;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(batchFileName);
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
if ( proc.ExitCode!= 0 )
```

in the batch file write something like this (sample for sql server)

```
osql -E -i %1
```