# Deploying my application that uses Entity Framework and creating databases on the client machine

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, deployment, database-deployment

I created the model in Entity Framework, and then created the database from that model.

What would be the best way of doing this in the client machine?

If Entity Framework try to connect to the database and find the necessary tables and those do not exist, it will give an error.

**What is the best way of create those tables in the client machine?**

**Using the SQL file generated by the model? If so, how can I execute it?**

In case that matters, I'm using SQL Server Express, although this question could be kind of generic for any database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy that script and use it in the client as well... I don't understand the problem of doing that.

This article has information on how to generate SQL script to generate DB.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=606

It say to right-click the entity-designer, and then "Generate Database from Model...", after that you enter the information of the DB connection, click next and you have the SQL.

**EDIT:**

Information on how to read and execute an SQL file:

I found this one in microsoft forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/43e8bc3a-1132-453b-b950-09427e970f31/

This question here in SO:

[How to execute an .SQL script file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c)

There is no native .Net way of doing that in a DB agnostic way I think.

Comment: It doesn't have to be executed from .NET. I just want a way to execute it in the client machine. No matter if I say to **my client**: `Do A, B, C` and then use the application

Comment: I guess I will keep all the SQL info in an string in my application and execute it using OleDb or similar.

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. I think that simplicity is the way to go. If you can tell him to do things before using app, that's ok! Use your time for what your clients care the most.