# WPF App run SQL Server Scripts

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sqlcommand

I often have to 'Generate Scripts' for stored procedures on SQL Server Management Studio.  I need to create a WPF app that will take the file produced and execute it.  I know you can do this:

```
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If I pass the entire scripts file text into sql, will this execute everything?

Comment: Why would you expect it to execute less than the Sql you passed it?

Comment: When I've used the above it's been to execute a stored procedure not CREATE, DROP, etc.  I assume it will run the entirety of the script but until I get the chance to test I wanted to know if SqlCommand would run anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this: [How to execute an .SQL script file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c-sharp)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

[...]

```
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sqlConnectionString = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=ccwebgrity;Data Source=SURAJIT\SQLEXPRESS";

    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"E:\Project Docs\MX462-PD\MX756_ModMappings1.sql");

    string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
    file.OpenText().Close();    
}
```

Comment: @user1166905 `SqlCommand` will work as long you don't have a `GO` statement in your sql script. If you strictly want to use `SqlCommand`, you'd have to split your file into separate statements and use them using a loop. Remove the 'GO' keywords and split the script into separate batches. Then execute each batch as its own `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Won't have the luxury of time to split it, have to try with Server above, doesn't seem to like it though despite adding Microsoft.SqlServer

Comment: @user1166905 The ADO.NET classes sadly don't understand `GO`-Statements. So if your script contains `GO`, this is the most efficient way to go, I'm afraid.

Comment: What References do you need to add for Server above, doesn't like it in the code whatever I do.

Comment: @user1166905 Take a look at the usings

Comment: I don't have the .Management, which reference contains this?

Comment: @user1166905 By default the DLL files are in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies`. Files: `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll`