# execute queries that aren't stored on DB

Tags: c#, sql

At work, we sometimes need to execute a SQL script (we open this .SQL file *-stored as C:\SQLScript\man.sql-*, set proper parameters and then execute it).
Right now I've create a C# application, this application is running on my computer and perform some operations against a DB server (the same server where the .sql script works) one of these operations include the execution of that script.

The problem is: how can I execute (from my C# application) the SQL script if it is stored as simple file rather than a real stored procedure?

Comment: What you are describing is a text file -- not a stored procedure on your hard drive.  You simply need to read the text from the file into your application and execute it as you would any inline SQL -- in most cases with a `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` -- or variance of depending on your database provider.

Comment: can u post a sample content of the file? Does it contain the `CREATE PROCEDURE` part, or is it just the SQL statements?

Comment: Is this a production DB? sounds pretty nasty, what permissions does the application user have on the DB?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a valid sql file and it executes as it is then all you have to do is

```
  string query = File.ReadAllText("yoursqlfilePath");
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query , connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @JoeEnos you edited too quickly, i was about to do this. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could open the file read it in and then execute an SQL command created from the file string and then execute the command.

I am not sure if there is a better way but that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally try and convert that to a stored procedure passing parameters which are needed. But you can look at the approach taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c-sharp). It basically reads the text from the script into a string and then executes it using ExecuteNonQuery. You can amend the text before calling ExecuteNonQuery.