# Execute postgres script with npgsql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, npgsql, executenonquery

I have a script (*.sql) which creates tables.
I am using Visual studio 2010 with npgsql to access postgres database.

Could I execute a script from codebehind?

This is the code I have tried:

```
string sqlConnectionString = @"myconnection";

FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"myfile.sql");

string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
file.OpenText().Close();
```

But But Visual studio dont recognize `Server`.

Comment: you could save it as a stored procedure in your db and call it from code behind

Comment: No, because I am going to execute in many different databases. I prefer to execute it from the application

Comment: you could save your query in a text file and load it as string an execute in your db's

Comment: I have it in a text file, I have tried to translate this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c-sharp

 to npgsql connector but no luck...

Comment: could you post the full code that you have tried? mask the ip's and other personal info, i just want to see the logic if possible please. also try executing a simple insert query just to rule out the possibility that your script fails

Comment: I have posted in my first post. Thanks!

Comment: put a breakpoint, which object fails to initialize first? `server`, `new ServerConnection(conn)`, `conn` or `script` ?

Comment: I got the answer. Look at the asnwer at the bottom. Thank you very much!!

Comment: In future, please try to always include any relevant code, *exact text* of error messages, your versions, etc. That said, +1 for useful self-answer.

Answer (score 11):

I got it. Here the answer:

```
NpgsqlConnection _connPg = new NpgsqlConnection("yourconnectionstring"));

FileInfo file = new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("DatabaseSchema.sql"));
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
var m_createdb_cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(script, _connPg);
_connPg.Open();
m_createdb_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
_connPg.Close();
```

Comment: Remove extra closing bracket at `new NpgsqlConnection("yourconnectionstring"))`.