# c#: MySQl execute sql file with parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

With MySqlCommand I'm tryting to execute a .sql that updates my database.

The large file contains updates, deletes, stored procedures and all. It also uses some variables like:

```
SET @_count := (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'easycertlistfwk_audit'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'AUDIT_TITLE'
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'TI_ORDER');
IF @_count = 0 THEN
            ALTER TABLE `AUDIT_TITLE`
            ADD COLUMN `TI_ORDER`  int(11) NULL AFTER `TI_DESCR`;
```

The code that I use to execute it withing c# is:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = File.ReadAllText(dbUpdatesFile);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() method rises an Exception telling me that @_count must be defined. I guess it takes it for one of the parameters that I'm supposed to pass to the command, but in this case, all the code (and hence temporary variable declarations) is within the sql file that I'd like just to execute.

How to do this? Is there a way to ignore params checking and binding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute an .SQL script file using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c-sharp)