# “exec sp_reset_connection" getting called after some specific alter db properties and causes script to fail

Tags: sql-server

My scenario is that I am calling multiple "ALTER DATABASE SET " commands followed by some table,index etc. creation commands from a sql script via C# following way:-

[How to execute an .SQL script file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c-sharp)

```
string sqlConnectionString = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=ccwebgrity;Data Source=SURAJIT\SQLEXPRESS";

string script = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Project Docs\MX462-PD\MX756_ModMappings1.sql");

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

The ALTER DB commands are like

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO
```

I have around 20 calls like this and after that calls to create tables, indexes, keys etc.

What I observe is that if I try to alter any of these following db properties

```
HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY    
TRUSTWORTHY  
DB_CHAINING
```

Then I see "exec sp_reset_connection" getting called in SQL Profiler and then it skips remaining commands being sent from the script from C# code.

This behavior has made my procedure not working properly from C# code but works fine from SSMS.

Can someone please explain this behavior of sp_reset_connection getting called after these specific db properties because in future I need to know what such properties can break code from C# while working in SSMS ?

There are few questions on SO regarding sp_reset_connection but those are about why they are called or enabling/disabling it etc. I couldn't find any relation of this SP to these three properties.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this..`This behavior has made my procedure not working properly from C# code but works fine from SSMS`

Comment: The following commands in the sql script are ignored if I call from C#. If I comment out altering these three properties the script works fine.

No matter at which line I alter any of these three properties the sp_reset_connection is called and script call stays incomplete.

Not sure is any caching of query plan is involved, but my assumption is that since I am changing the order of these in script, so it should not be cached.