# How to run scripts in Database which were stored in particular location through C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DB SQL script which is stored in location  C://Temp. I need to load it, run in database by using C#. which is best way to do it?. I am using microsoft dapper for db connectivity

Comment: Search first. It would take the same amount of time you resort to type this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute an .SQL script file using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c-sharp)