# Execute sql statement or procedure in .net entity framework core

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I created ASP.NET 5.0 Core-Web-API project and use package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version 5.0.13. Additionally I created a stored procedure with 2 parameters of type `DATE`. The procedure runs in sql management studio without errors.

```
var p1 = new SqlParameter("@From", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
p1.Value = new DateTime(2021, 11, 07);
var p2 = new SqlParameter("@To", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
p1.Value = new DateTime(2021, 12, 07);
List<MapTableDimvw> myList = myDbContext.MyTable.FromSqlRaw("EXEC myProc @From, @To", p1, p2).ToList();
```

Comment: Don't use `FromSqlInterpolated` in this case. EF tries to make a parameter of everything enclosed by '{}'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute an .SQL script file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @Scircia don't think so. I can run procedures in EF as well. But I don't know how to execute `new SqlCommand()` in EF via `FromRawSql` or `FromSqlInterpolated`.

Comment: just making sure whether you didn't copy \ paste your code properly here, or simply missed the error :
you call .Value on p1 twice (instead of calling .Value on p2 after creating the SqlParameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do with the following :

```
var blogs = context.myTable
.FromSqlRaw($"Select Id, colA, colB From myTable")
.ToList();
// or AsEnumerable();
var blogs = context.myTable
.FromSqlRaw($"Select Id, colA, colB From myTable")
.AsEnumerable();
```

Source: [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Otherwise, you can try to add something like this :

```
var simple = _context.myTable.FromSqlInterpolated($"Select Id, colA, colB From myTable").ToList();
```

Regards.

Comment: The problem is not that he cannot run the query, but that the query is in a file and cannot run it when he reads the statement out of the file.

Comment: Ok, but if you do that :
String sql = "your sql query";
var simple = myDbContext.myTable.FromSqlInterpolated("sql");
Is that working? It's just for understand if the problem is in the reading of the text file, or in the interpretation of the query.

Comment: Thx for help. As Gert Arnold mentioned and also explained [here](https://www.pmichaels.net/tag/fromsqlinterpolated/) I can't use pre-build string for `FromSqlInterpolated`. Inspired of your help I tried `stored procedures` instead. But then I run into errors by passing parameters. Ples c my edits.

Comment: Why you don't do simple that : 
`string myQueryString = string.Format("EXEC myProc {0}, {1}", p1, p2);` for prepare the SQL query, and after that
`List<MapTableDimvw> myList = myDbContext.MyTable.FromSqlRaw(myQueryString).ToList();`

Comment: I edit my question. And resolved the problem as u and Gert Arnold mentioned.